# How to set OnClick For a Recycler View Item Toast with position

Tags: java, android

I have Just Created a recycler View that contains Cards All I want to setOnCLick for this recycler view toast with a position item Click as It's ma first time to use a recycler view I always use a list View with a setOnItemClickListner so
Here's my Adapter Class

```
package abtech.waiteriano.com.retailstar.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import abtech.waiteriano.com.retailstar.R;

public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {

    public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cv;
        Context c;
        TextView InvoiceNumber;
        TextView InvoiceType;
        TextView InvoiceDate;
        TextView Status;
        TextView CustomerID;

        PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            InvoiceNumber = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.invoiceNo);
            InvoiceType = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvType);
            InvoiceDate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
            Status = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.statusTv);
            CustomerID = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cutomerId);
        }
    }

    List<Invoice> Invoices;

    RVAdapter(List<Invoice> Invoices){
        this.Invoices = Invoices;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
        PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
        personViewHolder.InvoiceNumber.setText(Invoices.get(i).invoiceNo);
        personViewHolder.InvoiceType.setText(Invoices.get(i).invoiceType);
        personViewHolder.InvoiceDate.setText(Invoices.get(i).invoiceDate);
        personViewHolder.Status.setText(Invoices.get(i).status);
        personViewHolder.CustomerID.setText(Invoices.get(i).cutomerId);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Invoices.size();
    }
}
```

and here's the fragment class which contains the recycler VIew

```
package abtech.waiteriano.com.retailstar.adapters;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import abtech.waiteriano.com.retailstar.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link InvoiceFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link InvoiceFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class InvoiceFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Reinvoice_number parameter arguments, choose invoice_numbers that match
    View rootView;
    private List<Invoice> Invoices;
    private RecyclerView rv;




    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Reinvoice_number and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public InvoiceFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment InvoiceFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Reinvoice_number and change types and number of parameters
    public static InvoiceFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        InvoiceFragment fragment = new InvoiceFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_invoice, container, false);
        rv=(RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        initializeData();
        initializeAdapter();


        return rootView;

    }
    private void initializeData(){
        Invoices = new ArrayList<>();
        Invoices.add(new Invoice("204", "Regular","15/5/2017","Regular","100200000194"));
        Invoices.add(new Invoice("205", "Regular","20/5/2017","Regular","100200000195"));
        Invoices.add(new Invoice("206", "Regular","30/5/2017","Regular","100200000196"));
        Invoices.add(new Invoice("207", "Regular","5/6/2017","Regular","100200000197"));
        Invoices.add(new Invoice("208", "Regular","10/6/2017","Regular","100200000198"));
        Invoices.add(new Invoice("209", "Regular","15/6/2017","Regular","100200000199"));
        Invoices.add(new Invoice("210", "Regular","20/6/2017","Regular","100200000200"));
        Invoices.add(new Invoice("211", "Regular","25/6/2017","Regular","100200000201"));
        Invoices.add(new Invoice("212", "Regular","30/6/2017","Regular","100200000202"));
    }

    private void initializeAdapter(){
        RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(Invoices);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // TODO: Reinvoice_number method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and invoice_number
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is implement onClickListener in your PersonViewHolder class inside your recyclerview adapter like this:

1. Make a Constructor
2. Set onClickListener on the itemview
3. Make toast in onClick function for the clicked item

Final edit will look like this -

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;

    public RVAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;

        }

    public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        CardView cv;
        Context c;
        TextView InvoiceNumber;
        TextView InvoiceType;
        TextView InvoiceDate;
        TextView Status;
        TextView CustomerID;

        PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            InvoiceNumber = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.invoiceNo);
            InvoiceType = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvType);
            InvoiceDate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
            Status = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.statusTv);
            CustomerID = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cutomerId);
            //set OnclickListener
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            //Do whatever you what with the position
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked Position"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    List<Invoice> Invoices;

    RVAdapter(List<Invoice> Invoices){
        this.Invoices = Invoices;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
        PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
        personViewHolder.InvoiceNumber.setText(Invoices.get(i).invoiceNo);
        personViewHolder.InvoiceType.setText(Invoices.get(i).invoiceType);
        personViewHolder.InvoiceDate.setText(Invoices.get(i).invoiceDate);
        personViewHolder.Status.setText(Invoices.get(i).status);
        personViewHolder.CustomerID.setText(Invoices.get(i).cutomerId);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Invoices.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get context from constructor then make toast inside onBindViewHolder() :

```
Context context;
RVAdapter(Context context, List<Invoice> Invoices){
    this.Invoices = Invoices;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int position) {
    personViewHolder.InvoiceNumber.setText(Invoices.get(i).invoiceNo);
    personViewHolder.InvoiceType.setText(Invoices.get(i).invoiceType);
    personViewHolder.InvoiceDate.setText(Invoices.get(i).invoiceDate);
    personViewHolder.Status.setText(Invoices.get(i).status);
    personViewHolder.CustomerID.setText(Invoices.get(i).cutomerId);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeToast(context, "Clicked position is : "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });
}
```

Inside your fragment :

```
RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(getActivity(), Invoices);
```

Comment: oh sorry, my mistake. i forgot about it